# "error: no match for operator==" when checking the value of a string

Tags: c++

How can I check if string is equal to '♦'?

Setting **some_string** to **4** and printing like this:

```
some_string = 4;
cout << some_string;
```

shows me this:

```
♦
```

But how can I test it? I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
if (some_string==4){

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you want real answer provide real information

Comment: [You could use an escape sequence like `'\x04'`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C#Table_of_escape_sequences) (or, if you want a string instead of a `char`, `"\x04"`).

Comment: Yes, it's a good thing you can't compare strings and integers.

Comment: @Cornstalks, You likely do. `operator==` doesn't work for strings and characters because it'd be too easy to give it something that isn't a character (like `4`). I suppose it might be possible to change that now and have one or more deleted overloads.

Comment: You might want to tell us what type `some_string` is

Comment: In general, if you want high quality answers make sure to give as much detail as possible. I'd recommend including a verbatim code snippet (types and so forth included) and a description of what you are actually trying to do. More information in the question gives a much higher probability of an accurate and complete answer.

Comment: @NathanCox I wanted to make it as simple as possible because I didn't want to waste anyone's time. I thought it was a very simple problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**
If you would like to test for the character with the character code 4, then you can do the following:

```
if(some_string == '\x04') {
    //Do something...
}
```

Comment: The character 4 is not the same as the character with the character code 4 (at least in anything I know of).

Comment: Chris, you are correct. I misunderstood his answer. I had thought he intended the character code. @chris

Answer (score 0):

String takes an input in the form of characters..

```
string some_string="4\0";
```

Always use "\0" aka NULL terminated character while initializing the strings as it tells that the string has ended otherwise program will continue to check the next consecutive locations in the memory which will result in an error.

You can use relational operator..

```
if(some_string=="some_value")
{
//Do Something....
}
```